# NoSuchFieldException in Android ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, scale

I try to use reflection to get field mMinSapn in android.view.ScaleGestureDetector

```
    ScaleGestureDetector  sgd = new ScaleGestureDetector(view.getContext(), sl);
    try {
        Field field = sgd.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMinSpan");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(sgd,1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it always has NoSuchFieldException, I find that it may be caused by ProGuard.
So I edit my proguard-rules.pro,add some code:

```
-keepclassmembers class android.view.ScaleGestureDetector {
private  <fields>;
}
```

or

```
-keepclassmembers class android.view.ScaleGestureDetector {
 private *;
}
```

it still has NoSuchFieldException.Something here is not right? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in [the `ScaleGestureDetector` source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java;l=147):

```
@UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, trackingBug = 123768938)
private int mMinSpan;
```

The `UnsupportedAppUsage` means that if you have a `targetSdkVersion` greater than 28 (the `Build.VERSION_CODES.P`, you cannot access `mMinSpan` at all, even via reflection as explained by the [Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces). As that page mentions, a `NoSuchFieldException` is expected when trying to access these non-SDK fields.

Of course, looking again [at the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java;l=204):

```
mMinSpan = viewConfiguration.getScaledMinimumScalingSpan();
```

And [`getScaledMinimumScalingSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration#getScaledMinimumScalingSpan()) **is** part of the public API in API 29 (exactly when you cannot access the field via reflection). Therefore you can run your reflection based code on API 28 or lower and use the public API on API 29 and higher:

```
ViewConfiguration viewConfiguration = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
in minSpan = viewConfiguration.getScaledMinimumScalingSpan();
```

Comment: Great! I get the value,but how to change it? it seem not have setScaledMinimumScalingSpan() method.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `ScaleGestureDetector` class into my project from `compileSdkVersion` 30.

At the same time, changed `mMinSpan`:

From:

```
mMinSpan = viewConfiguration.getScaledMinimumScalingSpan();
```

To:

```
mMinSpan = 0;
```